# JSF 2.0 Ajax Problem

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have some `<h:inputText>` on my form and two `<h:commandButton>`s, one commandbutton submits the form in a classic manner and the other one has a `<f:ajax>`, how can I prevent the form from submitting when the user presses Enter key in one of my inputs which triggers the second button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have textareas in your form, just add the following to the `<h:form>`.

```
<h:form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
```

The Enter key has the key code 13, so the above returns `false` to the form whenever it is been pressed, so the default action won't take place anymore.

However, if you have textareas in your form (`<h:inputTextArea>` and on), where you'd like to have the Enter key to function as usual, then you need to put the `onkeypress` attribute in all non-textarea input fields instead. You can use JS/jQuery for this to minimize code duplication.

Comment: this makes all the inputs don't submit the form by pressing Enter, but I need only one input like this. and I want to trigger the ajax listener.

Comment: Then put it on the individual input elements only for which you'd like to not submit the form by pressing enter.